# if statement in swift returns error about curly bracket

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have a if statement that I fixed recently, but now instead of the past error (see my most recent question), I get this error:

```
Braced block of statements is an unused closure
```

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class DAGNConfirmViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var DValueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var AValueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var GValueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var NValueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var TValueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ErrorField: UILabel!

    let nf = NSNumberFormatter()
    let DAGNViewControllerInstance: DAGNViewController = DAGNViewController()

    @IBAction func YESButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) { }

    @IBAction func NOButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) { }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.    

        DValueLabel.text = nf.stringFromNumber(DAGNViewControllerInstance.DValueVar)
        AValueLabel.text = nf.stringFromNumber(DAGNViewControllerInstance.AValueVar)
        GValueLabel.text = nf.stringFromNumber(DAGNViewControllerInstance.GValueVar)
        NValueLabel.text = nf.stringFromNumber(DAGNViewControllerInstance.NValueVar)
        TValueLabel.text = nf.stringFromNumber(DAGNViewControllerInstance.TValueVar)

        // If statement here
        if !(DAGNViewControllerInstance.DValueVar <= 5) ||
           !(DAGNViewControllerInstance.DValueVar >= 1) ||
           !(DAGNViewControllerInstance.AValueVar <= 6) ||
           !(DAGNViewControllerInstance.AValueVar >= 2) ||
           !(DAGNViewControllerInstance.GValueVar <= 3) ||
           !(DAGNViewControllerInstance.GValueVar) >= 2 ||
           !(DAGNViewControllerInstance.NValueVar <= 3) ||
           !(DAGNViewControllerInstance.NValueVar >= 1) ||
           !(DAGNViewControllerInstance.TValueVar <= 9999) ||
           !(DAGNViewControllerInstance.TValueVar >= 1) {
            self.ErrorField.text = "One or more values are not in range!"
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Why is this, and how do I fix it? I don't think I am missing a curly bracket. Does this error have anything to do with the placement of the curly bracket?

Comment: parentheses around the entire statement?

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: Oh my God. Dat condition! Don't you feel that it's *a little bit* redundant?

Comment: The error occurs on the entire if statement

Answer (score 1):

What you have wirtten as:

```
!(DAGNViewControllerInstance.GValueVar) >= 2
```

should be:

```
!(DAGNViewControllerInstance.GValueVar >=2 )
```

Comment: That's is strange. I pasted the code into a Playground and the only errors I'm getting are related to not knowing what a DAGNViewControllerInstance is.
Have you tried simplifying the if statement down to one condition and see if that works? If it does work, then add the other conditions back one by one until you find what is causing the error. I

Comment: Well I decided just to ditch the if statement and I made a switch, but thanks for the help!